# Is safe to store an access token in a client cookie if the cookie is not send to the server

Tags: php, security, backbone.js, cookies, laravel-4

I'm developing a backbone application with a REST api to a Laravel back end.
It means that I authenticate on every request, using the access token that I receive from the social media (eg. Facebook, Google, etc).

My plan was to store a client side cookie generated with Javascript to store the access token, so that I can send it to the back end to authenticate the user with my application, and so that it is possible to request resources on the server of the social medium (such as friends list, photos, etc).

Note that I make an additional check with the FB server in my back end with PHP.

> Question: Is it safe to store the access token in a browser cookie generated by Javascript when this cookie is never sent to the server?

For example, is this safe practice (see image below)?

Afaik, nobody should have access to this access except for the user him/herself.

If not, I really see no way how to perform safe (REST) authentication at all... 
I've been poundering about this question for a very long time now.

[image]

Comment: The big question is, how would somebody else get access to the client browser to get access to their cookie?

Comment: @MarkBaker I don't know. I wrote two subsequent questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177064/can-a-cookie-that-was-generated-with-javascript-not-send-in-the-header-by-the-s?noredirect=1#comment42843266_27177064 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177224/how-to-keep-state-at-the-client-safely

Comment: @MarkBaker It doesn't appear to be safe... I'm struggling hard to find some logical flow in this.

Comment: Unless the client machine has some malware that can read the cookies and send them elsewhere, or an attacker has physical access to the box, and as long as you're treating the cookies as secure and sending them over https, what attack vectors are you expecting to give an attacker access to that cookie?

Comment: The comment to my other question was: sure. inject some javascript, run a jsonp request, boom - your cookie is now out in the wild.

Comment: So you protect against javascript injected via xss: you should be doing that anyway.... there is no single, universal answer to security, you build a series of walls against different attack vectors

Comment: @MarkBaker Should I conclude that if I protect well against XSS (which has to be done anyway), I can use the js generated cookie to store the social medium access token?

Comment: You should protect to the best of your ability, using recommended best practises against all the different forms of attack; but (while remaining aware of new vulnerability alerts and ready to improve things) you shouldn't let the fear that you've not done enough prevent you from doing anything

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't store the fb auth cookie in the browser, but only in the server session, and would proxy requests through the server

Comment: Ok, but I'm not planning to use sessions, as I would like to follow the general rule of making every request independent and avoiding state at the server. Any serious post I read, it is recommended and I feel a strong preference towards it... If it is theoretically possible, then I will try my best to secure it as much as possible. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd also rename those cookies, so that they didn't tell me that you were using PHP and Laravel, and would change the PHP session cookie to use something like ripemd320 for its hash function

Comment: I'm going to eliminate the laravel cookie (set by Laravel itself) and PHP session cookie entirely if I figure out how to do.

Comment: There is no way of maintaining state without cookies, so you'd need to authenticate whenever you accessed you server

Comment: I fail to see much different with your own time-limited cookie, vs the Laravel or PHP cookies. They are all fundamentally the same thing. And if someone has comprimised the users computer, no amount of 'JS protection' is going to help you. You are overcomplicating this.

Comment: The difference would have been that I needed a way to store the access token from the oAuth provider at my client to make RESTful auth to both my own server and the server of the oAuth provider (backbone client application). But based on the question I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177224/how-to-keep-state-at-the-client-safely I decided to go back to keeping state at the server through sessions, although this was not my original intent.