# Can a cookie that was generated with Javascript (not send in the header by the server) be stolen / used by an attacker?

Tags: javascript

I save the cookie with Javascript, and I get the values from the cookie with Javascript.
I communicate the content of the cookie over https in the ajax header.
I will not use the server's session.

Is there any way the attacker can get to the content of the cookie?

Comment: sure. inject some javascript, run a jsonp request, boom - your cookie is now out in the wild.

Comment: If you're worried about an attacker intercepting the cookie, it shouldn't be an issue over HTTPS provided the `secure` flag is set: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100/how-can-i-check-that-my-cookies-are-only-sent-over-encrypted-https-and-not-http

Comment: This is driving me crazy. How can one ever keep state at the client using a FB access token? One should use it to access resources on one's own server, and also from the FB server. Assuming that one uses a js framework and REST authentication. It cannot be encrypted as such, and yet there is no other way than to use a cookie to keep state at the client.

Comment: Any cookie can get stolen if the attacker has access to the client browser. Can you describe the specific scenario(s) you are worried about?

Comment: @nullability I will post a new question with the contents of my last comment. I HAVE to find an answer to this question, there is just no way around it. Thanks.

Comment: If it's just FB, can't you just use call FB.getLoginStatus() and use the userID from the response object to access local resources?

Comment: @nullable I'm not worried a cookie being intercepted, I'm worried about the content of the cookie being jeopardised. frasnian Thanks, but the user has to be authenticated on each subsequent request.

Comment: Jeopardized in what way? The content of the cookie should only have meaning to your server (e.g. a unique hash). It can't be hidden from the client user and could remain on their hard drive forever, so there will always be the chance of the cookie being viewed by someone.

Comment: @nullability So as I replied as a comment on question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176869/is-safe-to-store-an-access-token-in-a-client-cookie-if-the-cookie-is-not-send-to?noredirect=1#comment42843607_27176869 : Should I conclude that if I protect well against XSS (which has to be done anyway), I can use the js generated cookie to store the social medium access token? I appear to be dealing with this question in a loop? -> Got a good answer in the previous post in the comments now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're worried about [Man in the Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). This could happen if you aren't using HTTPS with your browser cookie and/or you have mixed media where one of the insecure HTTP requests is sent with the cookie. Make sure it's encrypted using HTTPS, and then it's pretty secure (but not impossible to break w/ enough computational power)