# How to keep state at the client SAFELY?

Tags: javascript, php, security, cookies, laravel

Following this question: [Can a cookie that was generated with Javascript (not send in the header by the server) be stolen / used by an attacker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177064/can-a-cookie-that-was-generated-with-javascript-not-send-in-the-header-by-the-s?noredirect=1#comment42843230_27177064)

This is driving me crazy.
How can one ever keep state at the client using a FB access token?
One should use it to access resources on one's own server, and also from the FB server. Assuming that one uses a js framework (Backbone / Marionette) and REST authentication.
It cannot be encrypted as such, and yet there is no other way than to use a cookie to keep state at the client.

I have done plenty of research.
Every source mentions to keep state at the client, to avoid server sessions, yet I can't find a single source that explains how to do it safely.

If you know the answer, please share. 
Thanks.

Comment: simple: you don't keep any "sensitive" state on the client. storing `200" flat-screen tv, quantity 1` on the client side is trivial/easy. Storing `200" flat-screen tv, quantity 1, cost $999.99` is extraordinarily stupid. Someone'll go change that to `quantity 500, cost: $0.00` and laugh and laugh and laugh.

Comment: Thanks, but that's the point. So how can a Javascript application keep state at the client at all? From the sources I've read I learned that many developers use eg. basic auth, sending user login and password (!) over the network on every request when using RESTful auth. They must keep it at the client, how otherwise can it be?

Comment: @Kim Gysen: "From the sources I've read" --- so how those sources suggest to store it?

Comment: @zerkms They don't. That's where my frustration comes from.

Comment: @Kim Gysen: you cannot and don't store any sensitive information on a client. The end of story.

Comment: @zerkms If that is true, then I will use the default session system. I'm happy to finally(!) get an answer that is conclusive. Now a stupid question. Is the PHPSESSID cookie not sensitive as well? I wondered just now, if they can get the accesstoken from my cookie, they can get the session id as well (even if it is temporary)?

Comment: PHP session cookies are **JUST** the session's ID. it's a pseudo-random alphanumeric hash. The user can hack at that all they want, the odds of changing it to be smoeone else's session ID are very very low. Everything you store in php sessions is kept on the server, and ONLY the id of that session ever gets sent to the client. There's nothing the user can do to change the contents of the session array, because that's all on the server. at most they try and guess someone ELSE's session id and hijack that session.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for your answer, I'm switching back to sessions. Pff! :)

Answer (score 1):

You *can* store information on the client safely *if* the server is delivering it.
You can encrypt or sign the data using a secret key which only the server knows and decrypt/validate the information using it.

However, by definition, you cannot store information safely which is also generated on the client itself. It's just the client playing with itself. Anyone can inspect what exactly is going on, so you can't sign or encrypt anything using any secret key, because by definition the key ceases to be secret if you give it to every client. You can also not trust any information the client is sending to the server because the client is free to send anything to the server it wishes. You cannot trust any code running on the client because it is entirely out of your control.

Comment: Great. Anyhow, I'm moving back to using sessions to keep the state anyway. I need to store FB access tokens in the session to be able to make requests to their server when I need them. I cannot encrypt with a one way encryption, because that would render these tokens useless. I should also not store them in the database without encryption, because that's not safe either. So it seems the best solution for now. Let me know if you would disagree, I'm always open to useful input.

Comment: After re-reading it, I wonder how this is actually safer? If the server knows the secret key to decrypt the information and the browser stores the encrypted version, on request, it doesn't matter whether it's the browser or attacker who sends the encrypted information, is it? It would seem that the server will decrypt the encrypted information anyway.

Comment: Of course. The thing is, only the server knows the encryption key, only the server can encrypt the data. An attacker would not be able to produce valid encrypted information which can be validly decrypted using the secret server key.